# robot_localization and gmapping - how the transform should be done?

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, navsat-transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to use `robot_localization` and `gmapping`. What we have done so far: we use gmapping to publish the transform between `map` -> `odom`. Then we tried to apply gps, imu and odom using ekf from robot_localization. We use navsat_transform and one ekf node to fuse all the data. This node does `odom` -> `base_link` transform. This setting does not work very well.

Here: https://roscon.ros.org/2015/presentations/robot_localization.pdf (page 4) there is a picture: [localization and navigation http://slideplayer.com/slide/8827261/26/images/4/robot_localization+and+the+ROS+Navigation+Stack.jpg](http://slideplayer.com/slide/8827261/26/images/4/robot_localization+and+the+ROS+Navigation+Stack.jpg)

This indicates, that I should fuse gmapping and navsat_transform result in one localization node. Should this be done? How should it be done? Is there an example of it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269388/robot_localization-and-gmapping---how-the-transform-should-be-done?/) by [Ago](https://answers.ros.org/users/31489/ago/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [juanlu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29661/juanlu/) on 2017-08-23**:
Can you tell us how are you configuring gmapping and robot_localization? Specifically the parameters base_frame and odom_frame in gmapping and the parameter base_link_frame in robot_localization.

Also, have you tried other robot_localization packages? like robot_pose_ekf for example.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-08-23**:
As explained in the presentation video: The upper is a either-or relation. So you fuse either gmapping or amcl or navsat_transform. This is because all these nodes provide an absolute position.

**Comment by [Ago](https://answers.ros.org/users/31489/ago/) on 2017-08-23**:
Haven't tried robot_pose_ekf. base frame is base_footprint, odom frame is odom. In robot_localization, base_link_frame is base_footprint.
About Humpelstilzchen's comment, how could I use laser and gps together?

**Comment by [Deep](https://answers.ros.org/users/32240/deep/) on 2017-10-14**:
I am have the same issue. Any help please.

**Comment by [Robbe_C](https://answers.ros.org/users/34238/robbe_c/) on 2018-04-02**:
Hey, Ago and Deep, did you get your setup to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a pretty complex configuration! You're not fusing the gmapping output into the EKF in some way, are you?

This is also probably not going to play well with loop closure, unless you have a GPS with high accuracy.

In any case, it's almost impossible to make a determination about what's not working in your setup without at least your launch files and sample input messages.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robbe_C](https://answers.ros.org/users/34238/robbe_c/) on 2018-04-08**:
Hello Tom Moore

How would you handle this problem if you had gmapping, imu and GPS?
Is it possible to use the gmapping with a gps? or do you have to choose between them?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-04-09**:
The problem is that your `map` frame will constantly be shifting any time gmapping closes a loop, so the `navsat_transform_node` transform to your world frame will be constantly invalidated. Once you *have* a map, then you can use GPS data, I suppose, but only *after* you localize in the map.

**Comment by [Robbe_C](https://answers.ros.org/users/34238/robbe_c/) on 2018-04-09**:
Ok, thanks for the reply!
If I understand it correctly, it's not a good idea to use gps in combination with gmapping.
Is it a better idea to use a combination of gmapping and imu if the laser scanner data is available
and use gps in combination with imu if it's not available?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-04-12**:
The answer to this is far too long to put in a comment, I'm afraid. Please ask a separate question. Thanks.

**Comment by [Robbe_C](https://answers.ros.org/users/34238/robbe_c/) on 2018-04-12**:
Ok, I have posted my question: https://answers.ros.org/question/288429/how-to-set-up-robot_localization-with-gmapping-imu-and-gps/